# How to insert Bitmap into HashMap

Tags: android, android-layout

Well, I've been trying to insert images from the the Web into a Listview. When I use images from drawable file, inserting "R.drawable.paris (foto file name)", everything goes ok. But when I try to use a Bitmap object, the image just do not appear on the screen. Anybody could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class TesHashBitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ListView listCities = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.citylist);

        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagedisplay);
        img.setImageBitmap(photo);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> citiesmap  =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        HashMap<String, Object> citmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        citmap.put("Photo", photo);
        citmap.put("Nation", "France");
        citiesmap.add(citmap);


        SimpleAdapter sadapt = new SimpleAdapter(this, citiesmap, R.layout.lines, new String[] {"Photo","Nation"}, new int[] {R.id.photoimg,R.id.contentline});

        listCities.setAdapter(sadapt);
        }
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity why are you not using Bitmap in your Hashmap? Why are you using Object?  Also, I'm pretty sure that SimpleAdapter doesn't take ArrayList, it needs a regular Array.

Comment: Because I'm planing to add more data on the Listview. Actually, that code is just part of a new appplication.

Comment: did you able to solve this problem? if yes then please write answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not understanding ListView correctly...

Take a look at this tutorial...

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

The thing you're clearly missing is how you define the View that the list view uses as its template (for an individual element to be displayed).  You can't just toss it a list of images and have it figure stuff out.  You need to provide it with a View template that it will repurpose over and over, and then give it the appropriate values to populate into those Views.

In the example above, look for `R.layout.rowlayout`. That's where he explains how to use a custom View as your list element.

And welcome to Stack! :) Don't forget to mark correct answers as such, and upvote the ones that you find most helpful.

Comment: Hey Dr.Dredel. Well, actually I set a View for the ListView. The XML file is quite simple, it's just a TextView and a Imageview. That works, cause when I use "drawable.R.id.img1" as parameter instead of photo object, that works perfectly. The issue is to insert a Bitmap object into the Hashmap. This is a part of news application, so I'll need to get images from the Web.

Comment: There can't be an 'issue' in inserting a bitmap into a hashmap since this is all just memory space association. If you launch the debugger and look at your hashmap after you have populated it, I'm sure you'll see your bitmaps sitting there, as they should. R.drawable.img1 isn't a bitmap, it's an int that points to a resource. I haven't looked your code over very closely, but I would definitely look at changing your Object to a Bitmap and then following the advice on that tutorial on how to get the whole magilla into your ListView.